# PHP $this use inside class to reference class

Tags: php, this, this-pointer

I have a function `loadModule();` in class `core`, but to load modules I need to define variables in the construct, and many of them require core. Would I simply use `loadModule("someModule", $settings, $dbc, $core, $etc...);` or `loadModule("someModule", $settings, $dbc, $this, $etc...);` since this function is in the core class that is defined by $core? I'm confused right now, and help would be appreciated. Thanks

EDIT:

Intended use would look something like
`$this->core->loadModule("initialLoad, $settings, $version, $dbc, $parser, $layout);`

The module construct would look like

```
public function __construct($settings, $version, $dbc, $layout, $core, $parser){
    $this->settings = $settings;
    $this->version = $version;
    $this->dbc = $dbc;
    $this->layout = $layout;
    $this->core = $core;
    $this->parser = $parser;

}
```

Comment: Can you provide a short example of intended use?

Comment: One thing it sound like you may be be able to take advantage of is class constants

Comment: @Rasclatt What is that? I've never heard of it before. Edit: Is that like core::function();

Comment: So the $core would be itself (the containing class) as a resource?

Comment: @Rasclatt This scenario is in the page generation which is outside of core. I suppose loading modules could be put in the page class though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look into dependency injection. Perhaps use something like [pimple](http://pimple.sensiolabs.org/).

Have your container initialize all your modules. If you need to get into more advance use you could probably proxy the services so that they're lazy instantiate at first time use.

Then you could probably inject core into the classes and use the loaded modules however you like.

Comment: So this (and Rasclatt's comment(s)) led me to an idea; having the module loader in the page initiation class. Technically this would make more sense because it's not used much and would eliminate this problem